# undefined index after submitting form

Tags: php, url, foreach, indexing, undefined

---

```
<?php

include 'includes/connectie.php';

$product_id=$_GET['id'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  `producten` WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
    $sql_result = $dbh->query($sql);

    foreach($sql_result as $row)
        {   
            $prijs=$row['prijs'];
            $product_naam=$row['product_naam'];
            $product_categorie=$row['product_categorie'];
            $product_specificaties=$row['product_specificaties'];
            $foto=$row['foto'];
            $product_id=$row['product_id']; 
            $product_soort=$row['product_soort'];


            echo "Product id nummer:", $product_id;

        }

//$_SESSION['prijs'] = $prijs;


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

if (!empty($product_naam) && !empty($product_specifcaties) && !empty($product_categorie) &&     
!empty($prijs)
&& !empty($product_soort)) {
    print "Product aangepast!";
    $sql = "UPDATE producten 
    SET prijs='$prijs', product_naam='$product_naam', 
    product_specificaties='$product_specificaties',
    product_categorie='$product_categorie', product_soort='$product_soort'
    WHERE product_id='$product_id'";

    $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $result = $query->execute();
    exit();
  }



}

?>


<html>
<form name="admin" action="producten_echt_aanpassen.php" method="POST" id="adminform" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>
        <label for 'product_naam'>Naam: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="product_naam" value="<?php print $product_naam; ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p> <label for 'product_specificaties'>Specificaties: </label><br>
        <textarea rows= "4" cols="50" name="product_specificaties"><?php print $product_specificaties; ?>
        </textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for 'prijs'>Prijs: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="prijs" value="<?php print $prijs; ?>"/>
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for 'product_categorie'>Iphone: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="product_categorie" value="<?php print $product_categorie; ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for 'product_soort'>Soort: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="product_soort" value="<?php print $product_soort; ?>"/>
    </p>
      <br/>
        <label for 'uploadfile'>Kies foto <img src="<?php print $foto; ?>"></label><br>
        <input type="file" name="file" ><br><br>


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</html>
```

the variable is loaded in a form in which product details can be changed. the form links to this page with the code above. but whenever I submit the form and try to change te detail i get an error of an undefined index. which is what the $_GET does in line 5. The foreach loop needs the index to be defined but whenever the form is submitted, the index in the URL is gone so the loop doesnt produce the variables that need to go to the database. I hope this makes sense. Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Show your HTML for the form please. Likely you are not passing the ID.

Comment: Or you're passing the ID as a hidden field, in which case it would be `$_POST['id']`, not `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: You don't seem to be passing the ID at all, you can either pass it like this `action="producten_echt_aanpassen.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"` or do as Barmar suggests (a better solution) and pass it in a hidden field.

Comment: i added the form. the form is in the same document as the php code.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/michael/public_html/producten_echt_aanpassen.php on line 6. This is the error i get.. I tried to change the $_GET['id'] into $_POST['id'] but then i get the error whever i enter the page for the first time(the second time is to confirm that changes are made to the database)

Comment: it looks like when I change the action to action="producten_echt_aanpassen.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>", like what you told me @FDL. I dont get the error anymore. But there is no change in the database. Is there anything wrong with my sql code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your html does not include a field named id.
2. You are sending the form as POST not GET, so after you add the correct field in the HTML you need to refer to it as `$product_id = $_POST['id']`;
3. No need for `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, it will only be helpful when you are uploading files. Otherwise it can cause you problems.

   ```
   <p>
       <label for 'product_naam'>Naam: </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="product_naam" value="<?php print $product_naam; ?>"/>
   </p>
   <p> <label for 'product_specificaties'>Specificaties: </label><br>
       <textarea rows= "4" cols="50" name="product_specificaties"><?php print $product_specificaties; ?>
       </textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
       <label for 'prijs'>Prijs: </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="prijs" value="<?php print $prijs; ?>"/>
   </p>
    <p>
       <label for 'product_id'>Product ID: </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php print $product_id; ?>"/>
   </p>
       <p>
       <label for 'product_categorie'>Iphone: </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="product_categorie" value="<?php print $product_categorie; ?>"/>
   </p>
   <p>
       <label for 'product_soort'>Soort: </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="product_soort" value="<?php print $product_soort; ?>"/>
   </p>
     <br/>
       <label for 'uploadfile'>Kies foto <img src="<?php print $foto; ?>"></label><br>
       <input type="file" name="file" ><br><br>


       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   ```

Hope this helps!